# Array contain null values store in some others section of null values

Tags: javascript, arrays, null, key

```
var dataList = [ 
                 { date: '2019-08-08', class: null, users: 21 },
                 { date: '2019-08-08', class: 'lower', users: 21 },  
                 { date: '2019-08-08', class: 'upper', users: 3}
                 { date: '2019-08-08', class: 'middle', users: 5}

               ];
```

I want this if array key contain `null` i want to store in like this
i have multiple dates in array and every array contains one null values

```
store null into "Others" key 
var dataList = [ 
                { date: '2019-08-08', class: 'Others', users: 21 },
                { date: '2019-08-08', class: 'lower', users: 21 },  
                { date: '2019-08-08', class: 'upper', users: 3}
                { date: '2019-08-08', class: 'middle', users: 5}
              ];
```

Comment: It's not very clear, can you please express the question better ?

Answer (score 0):

Using a `forEach` loop

```js
var dataList = [ 
                 { date: '2019-08-08', class: null, users: 21 },
                 { date: '2019-08-08', class: 'lower', users: 21 },  
                 { date: '2019-08-08', class: 'upper', users: 3},
                 { date: '2019-08-08', class: 'middle', users: 5}

               ];
dataList.forEach(function(e){
if(e.date==null)
e.date='Others'
if(e.class==null)
e.class='Others'
if(e.users==null)
e.users='Others'
})
console.log(dataList)
```

Comment: Upvote and mark it as correct ao it can help others too

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` like so:

```js
 

var dataList = [ 
             { date: '2019-08-08', class: null, users: 21 },
             { date: '2019-08-08', class: 'lower', users: 21 },  
             { date: '2019-08-08', class: 'upper', users: 3},
             { date: '2019-08-08', class: 'middle', users: 5}

           ];

const res = dataList.map(({ class: c, ...r }) => ({ class: c == null ? "Other" : c, ...r }));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array.map()`:

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
var dataList = [ 
                 { date: '2019-08-08', class: null, users: 21 },
                 { date: '2019-08-08', class: 'lower', users: 21 },  
                 { date: '2019-08-08', class: 'upper', users: 3},
                 { date: '2019-08-08', class: 'middle', users: 5}

               ];
               
let newList = dataList.map( (obj) => obj.class == null? { ...obj, class: "Other" } : obj );
```

If you need to check for ANY key in obj and not just for `class` key- comment here and i'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple code is as follows

```
dataList=dataList.map(x=>{x.class=x.class||"Others";return x})
```

```js
var dataList = [ 
                 { date: '2019-08-08', class: null, users: 21 },
                 { date: '2019-08-08', class: 'lower', users: 21 },  
                 { date: '2019-08-08', class: 'upper', users: 3},
                 { date: '2019-08-08', class: 'middle', users: 5}

               ];
               
dataList=dataList.map(x=>{x.class=x.class||"Others";return x})

console.log(dataList)
```